# Magento2 PageBuilder does not support Enter as new Line

Tags: magento2, html, page-builder

I had these type of text in my pagebuilder's HTML element : https://prnt.sc/dqb1EYcPIqgK

but in frontend it is showing like this : https://prnt.sc/EGisDha1RV0k

can anyone help me?

Comment: You should use HTML tag - </br>, because PageBuilder is support only html elements.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code must be valid, all CSS & JavaScript must be wrapped in their HTML elements,Only then your content show in correct way.

You have to add the html code in following way

**Input :**
[image]

**Output :**
[image]